# Thank-you letter incorrect contribution currency

Tags: contributions, message-templates, smarty, currency

My setup: CiviCRM 5.20.0 on Drupal 7.

I entered contributions in different currencies.
In Find Contributions, check some entries. At Actions select Thank-you letter print or email.

I put tokens Contributions:

`{contribution.currency} {contribution.total_amount} {contribution.fee_amount} {contribution.net_amount}`

and it gives me lines like these:

CNY HK$ 1,299.90 HK$ 0.00 HK$ 1,299.90

GBP HK$ 500.00 HK$ 0.00 HK$ 500.00

where CNY and GBP are the currencies of those contributions and HK$ is the symbol of the default currency.

It seems the amounts variables just took the system default.

Would you suggest some work-around? e.g. how to strip the wrong currency symbol.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried qualifiers like |replace:'HK$':'' but it breaks the smarty tag.

Comment: I did this: At CRM/Utils/Token.php line 1814 add a format parameter '%a' as a quick an dirty fix. Obviously future updates will overwrite my code. How can I make my code update-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - there's a bug worth reporting here, but I understand your priority is getting these letters out.  This should do the trick:

- Go to **Administer menu » Localizations » Languages, Currency, Locations**.
- Change **Monetary Amount Display** to `%a`.

Comment: Posted at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/111